# Want to run a COUNT on sub SELECT with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I want to count rows returned by subselect with Doctrine. The subselect I have is:

```
SELECT e FROM \comments\Entities\Event e 
WHERE e.type = 'addComment'
HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, e.commentedOnPublished, e.created) < 60)
```

In SQL I'd achieve the desired result with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT e.* FROM square_events as e 
    WHERE e.type = 'addComment' 
    HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, e.commentedOnPublished, e.created) < 60
) temp
```

Does anyone know how this could be achieved with Doctrine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure I'd already tried this and a thousand other solutions, anyway this is what I ended up with after one of our systems guys pointed out I was being an idiot!

```
SELECT COUNT(e) as eventCount FROM comments\Entities\Event e 
WHERE e.type = 'addComment'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, e.commentedOnPublished, e.created) < 60
```

One of those days...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the reason for wanting a subselect. The following should work just fine:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT COUNT(e.id) FROM \comments\Entities\Event e 
    WHERE e.type = 'addComment'
    HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, e.commentedOnPublished, e.created) < 60)"
);

$count = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: Thanks @timdev, turns out not using SQL for couple of years has made me a bit rusty.